# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PyScrolledWindow' in wxPython

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

My python version is 2.7 and wxPython ver 3.0 for python 32 bit 2.7 version.  I was currently working on a GUI app with wxPython. I tested my code it was working fine, I paused my work saved my files. I started to install some software on my machine. Then when I again started to continue my work with wxPython suddenly I started to receive an error. The complete error is given below. I don't understand the reason. I didn't edit my code too. However I am able to execute my other python programmes.

Error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\lib\scrolledpanel.py", line 21, in <module>
    class ScrolledPanel( wx.PyScrolledWindow ):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PyScrolledWindow'
```

I reinstalled wxPython but nothing changed. I tried to investigate using google. But all in vain. Can some provide me some advice on this?

The python code has following import statements:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel
```

and I using the imports like this:

```
panel = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(self, -1, size=(1000,500), pos=(0,50), style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: try adding the line `wx = wx` after `import wx`. Let me know what you get after doing that...

Comment: @gravetii I'll try. currently I am reinstalling python and wxPython. I'll update as soon as I try your solution.

Comment: If you are reinstalling anyway, try a bit older version than 3.0.

Comment: @gravetii nothing changed by using your idea. Same error.

Comment: @Fenikso I am using python 2.7.6 and wxPython 32-bit Python 2.7.

Comment: Your directory says `wx-3.0-msw`. You are definitely using wxPython 3.0 for Python 2.7.

Comment: @Fenikso thats strange I just reinstalled wxPython 2.7 and the error is still the same.

Comment: There is no wxPython 2.7 (this version number is like 7 years old). You have wxPython version number mixed with your Python version number. Try `print wx.version()`. If you still have problems, try installing older version of wxPython, I suspect version 3.0 to have some bugs. See http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/ for older versions.

Comment: @Fenikso you are right. I edited my post. I#ll try with old versions and let you know.

Comment: @Fenikso tried old wxPython version 2.9 too. Same problem

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46757/discussion-between-fenikso-and-pss)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our chat: You have your project files located on Desktop. There are probably many more `.py` files on your desktop. Some of them shadow your imported library name, maybe something like `wx.py`. So instead of importing `wx` library, you import something else, what does not have needed contents.

Try running your code in a more controlled environment, e.g. create a directory for your project, double check file names in that directory and your Python path for shadowing names. It should work.

Comment: @fenisko Thanks, This is quite a strange problem it can even happen if there is no file named wx.py or something. (This was my case). The lesson learnt by me is to programme in a controlled & clean environment.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
import wxversion
wxversion.select('3.0')
import wx
```

Answer (score 0):

Following has worked for me:

```
import wxversion
wxversion.select('3.0')
import wx
```

**PS** *When you use python env, you may see a tip "select xxx".*

Comment: Answer can be a little more detailed and code should be highlighted .you can give examples to support your answer.